# Embed ADF asset file in Tango Unity project

Tags: google-project-tango

The developer guide about [Area Learning in Unity](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-codelab-area-learning) explains how to load an Area Description File which is on the device running the app, using [AreaDescription.GetList()](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/area-description#getlist).

But is it possible to embed an ADF file in the Unity project and load it at runtime?

If yes, what would the C# code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is plenty of ways to do that, the approach I had in my app was to put the ADF file in "StreamingAssets" so I can access it in run time. Then I used the following method:
https://gist.github.com/Cocottier/c177ee2fb4ffdb727f2512a5b032ae01

Cheers!

Comment: It finally worked after fixing the paths construction in your sample code. Thanks!